# Hibernate: how to identify cause of SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, uniqueidentifier, unique-key

How can I identify the property name in bean which caused **SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException** Hibernate exception to be thrown? I have two unique columns: username, email.

which one is the cause of the exception?

Comment: you have to share your code please